# Add CloudFront Whitelist Headers to YAML template

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I would like some assistance with CloudFront distributions and their YAML templates if anyone has experience here.

We use cloudfront for an internal CDN for media files, to get around a tainted canvas error in the UI (selecting a poster image for a video) I have manually added some headers to the white list and this resolved the issue.

[image: Whitelist Headers]

This needs to be part of our automated deployments however and I cannot seem to find anything concrete on how to replicate this via a YAML template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues.html):

> Specifies the headers that you want Amazon CloudFront to forward to the origin for this cache behavior (whitelisted headers). For the headers that you specify, Amazon CloudFront also caches separate versions of a specified object that is based on the header values in viewer requests.

```
Cookies:
  Cookies
Headers:
  - String
QueryString: Boolean
QueryStringCacheKeys:
  - String
```

When navigating through AWS template documentation, use the `Type` links to dig further into specifications.

As an aside, I prefer to use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html#headers) to configure these resources:

```
cache_behavior {
  forwarded_values {
    headers = ["Host"]
  }
}
```